# Visual Studio Unit Testing Accessor, how to re-generate them without closing VS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Sometime, when the Unit Test of a class has been done and method use _Accessor while the code has changed. What ever you compile many time it still doesn't "synchronize" the _Accessor file. The only thing that work is closing VS2008 and reopend it. Any trick to "regenerate" the Testing Accessor?

Comment: Don't use the Accessor. Unit tests should only test against public members of a type (protected counts as public, because you can alway create a test-specific specialization that exposes protected members via a public wrapper member).

Comment: @Mark Seemann aren't you doing the same by declaring special protected members except that you have to jump through several hoops.

Comment: Given the context of the question I think it's fairly obvious who's jumping through most hoops :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the class where the private/protected method is located. Right click and choose "Create Private Accessor" and choose the proper test project.

Comment: This menu option is not always available. It's not showing up at all in VS2010 right now, with no explanation

Answer (score 3):

**Regenerating all accessors en masse**

1. Search for all *_accessor.* files in your project folders and delete them (be sure not to delete any files which you have created yourself). Most of these will be found in the Release/debug folders and test folders created by VS.
2. Rebuild your solution.

Note: Doing a clean or rebuild does not delete the accessor dll/pdb files so we are doing it manually here.